# save a pandas.Series histogram plot to file

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

In ipython Notebook, first create a pandas Series object, then by calling the instance method .hist(), the browser displays the figure.

I am wondering how to save this figure to a file (I mean not by right click and save as, but the commands needed in the script).

Comment: This question is for a single plot of one column. See [Saving plots (AxesSubPlot) generated from python pandas with matplotlib's savefig](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19555525/7758804) for dealing with subplots from plotting multiple columns.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Use the `Figure.savefig()` method, like so:

```
ax = s.hist()  # s is an instance of Series
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('/path/to/figure.pdf')
```

It doesn't have to end in `pdf`, there are many options. Check out [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig).

Alternatively, you can use the `pyplot` interface and just call the `savefig` as a function to save the most recently created figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s.hist()
plt.savefig('path/to/figure.pdf')  # saves the current figure
```

### Plots from multiple columns

- Added from a comment [toto_tico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060349/toto-tico) made on 2018-05-11
- If you are getting this error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'`, then it is likely that you are plotting multiple columns.

  - In this case, `ax` will be an array of all the axes.

```py
ax = s.hist(columns=['colA', 'colB'])

# try one of the following
fig = ax[0].get_figure()
fig = ax[0][0].get_figure()

fig.savefig('figure.pdf')
```

Comment: These techniques do not seem to save the labels. Only the core of the chart is saved.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `ax.figure.savefig()`:

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0, 1])
ax = s.plot.hist()
ax.figure.savefig('demo-file.pdf')
```

This has no practical benefit over `ax.get_figure().savefig()` as suggested in Philip Cloud's answer, so you can pick the option you find the most aesthetically pleasing. In fact, [`get_figure()` simply returns `self.figure`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2108af1b75fc9100d7ca081d83cf17d8653591ea/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L682-L684):

```py
# Source from snippet linked above
def get_figure(self):
    """Return the `.Figure` instance the artist belongs to."""
    return self.figure
```

Answer (score 12):

You can simply save your (e.g. histogram) plot like this:

```
df.plot.hist().get_figure().savefig('name')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add that the default resolution is 100dpi, which is fine for screen but won't work if you want to enlarge or print it. You can pass a 'dpi' parameter to get a high-resolution file:

```
ax = s.hist()  # s is an instance of Series
ax.figure.savefig('/path/to/figure.png', dpi=300)
```