# Save pandas.DataFrame.hist with multiple axes in one figure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with 24 columns, and I use the function `pandas.DataFrame.hist` to generate a figure with some subplots.

```
plot = df.hist(figsize = (20, 15))
plot


array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000018D47EB8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001C1200B8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001C1EADD8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001C20A4A8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B61AB38>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B61AB70>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B671898>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B698F28>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B6C85F8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B6F2C88>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B723358>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B74A9E8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B77B0B8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B7A1748>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B7C8DD8>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B7F84A8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B821B38>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B853208>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B87B898>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B8A2F28>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B8D35F8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B8FAC88>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B92C358>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B9549E8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000001B9850B8>]],
      dtype=object)
```

The problem is when I try to save this figure in a single PNG file I get an error

```
plot.savefig(os.path.join(folder_wd, folder_output, folder_dataset,'histogram.png'))
```

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'savefig'

None of the articles that I have checked so far has offered a solution

[Pandas visualisation guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html)
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555525/saving-plots-axessubplot-generated-from-python-pandas-with-matplotlibs-savefi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`savefig` is not a method of the `plot` object returned by the `df.hist`. Try the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# rest of your code

plot = df.hist(figsize = (20, 15))
plt.savefig(os.path.join(folder_wd, folder_output, folder_dataset,'histogram.png'))
```