# Can I save to disk a plot generated by pandas df.plot?

Tags: python, pandas

With pandas it is easy to plot a DataFrame:

```
df.plot()
```

This is much simpler than using matplotlib. However, with matplotlib one can save the plot to disk:

```
fig.savefig(path, format = format)
```

Is it possible to save a plot created by `df.plot()` in a similar way?

Comment: just use `plt.savefig(...)` where plt is imported as follows: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18992172

Comment: BTW: `pandas` uses `matplotlib` to draw plots so many elements from `matplotlib` tutorials may work in `pandas`.